# How to add a python matplotlib interactive figure to vue.js web app?

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, matplotlib

I have a plot made using `Python` `matplotlib` that updates every time new sensor data is acquired. I also have a web GUI using `vue`. I'd like to incorporate the `matplotlib` figure into the web GUI and have it update as it does when running it independently. This therefore means not just saving plot and loading it as an image.

Can anyone advise how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it's not reasonable way, There are very good visualizing tools powered by javascript, for example chart.js.
you can do your computation with python in back-end and pass data to front-end by API and plot every interactive diagrams you want using javascript.